# Removing runtime dependency on Python

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to remove runtime dependency of ROS on Python. Catkin, the build system, may need python for code generation from messages; but how difficult it is to use only C++ libs when ROS runs on any target ? Has anybody in the community given a try ?

Thanks in advance !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277821/removing-runtime-dependency-on-python/) by [ameybits](https://answers.ros.org/users/32950/ameybits/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-20**:
Could you be a bit more specific about what you mean with "when ROS runs on any target"? Are we just talking a nr of off-board developed nodes which participate in a node graph that is managed also off-board, or a full ROS dev environment?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-20**:
And to avoid an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info/): what is it you're trying to achieve? There may be easier ways.

**Comment by [ameybits](https://answers.ros.org/users/32950/ameybits/) on 2017-12-20**:
Hello gvdhoorn
My question was in context of running ROS on an embedded system, which may not have python on. It may be running a custom linux distro built by yocto; just as an example.  In this case, is it possible to remove python based packages from ROS and run it with only c++ packages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-20**:
In general: removing Python from everything will be difficult, as Python is used extensively throughout ROS (the master is pure Python fi). Deploying a subset that doesn't use Python is probably doable, but things like `rosrun` and `roslaunch` will not work. Depending on how much convenience ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-20**:
.. you'd like to maintain, this shouldn't be too much of a blocker though.

As to use of ROS on embedded systems with off-board built rootfs, you might want to take a look at [bmwcarit/meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros): a "ROS Layer for OpenEmbedded Linux".

**Comment by [ameybits](https://answers.ros.org/users/32950/ameybits/) on 2017-12-20**:
Yes. The original catkin system can also be leveraged for off-board cross compilation by overriding default compiler and sysroot paths in cmake.
Any idea whether python free flavor of ROS is on the contributor's agenda ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-20**:
I'm not privy to what everyone else is planning to do / doing, but I'm not aware of any work towards something that does *not* use Python. On the contrary even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on what all you need to do on the embedded system, you might be able to benefit from [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial). There is even a version specially for [embedded linux](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_embeddedlinux) and great [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_embeddedlinux/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1